# server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name by django

Tags: apache2.4, django-3.0, centos8

my django application(ssl) is strange...

This is the application structure. there is 4 apps.

```
mysite
 |-app1
 |-app2
 |-app3
 |-app4
```

main app is app1. now, there is response follows.

```
mysite
 |-app1 ...500 server error
 |-app2 ...200 ok
 |-app3 ...200 ok
 |-app4 ...200 ok
```

Below is the actual url
app1: https://www.henojiya.net/vietnam_research/
app2: https://www.henojiya.net/gmarker/
app3: https://www.henojiya.net/shopping/
app4: https://www.henojiya.net/kanban/

mmm...

```
# tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

openssl??

```
[Tue Aug 25 22:28:49.164124 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 8122:tid 140202116692224] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Tue Aug 25 22:28:49.183968 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 8122:tid 140202116692224] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Tue Aug 25 22:28:49.186372 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 8122:tid 140202116692224] AH00489: Apache/2.4.37 (centos) OpenSSL/1.1.1c mod_wsgi/4.7.1 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Aug 25 22:28:49.186393 2020] [core:notice] [pid 8122:tid 140202116692224] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

```
# tail -f ssl_error_log
```

server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name ??

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 5344:tid 140508085110528] [remote 54.67.71.54:39392]   File "/var/www/html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
[Tue Aug 25 18:28:39.109567 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5344:tid 140508085110528] [remote 54.67.71.54:39392]     "Unable to import required dependencies:\\n" + "\\n".join(missing_dependencies)
[Tue Aug 25 18:28:39.109575 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5344:tid 140508085110528] [remote 54.67.71.54:39392] ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
[Tue Aug 25 18:28:39.109578 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5344:tid 140508085110528] [remote 54.67.71.54:39392] numpy: Interpreter change detected - this module can only be loaded into one interpreter per process.
[Tue Aug 25 21:03:53.627872 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 7430:tid 139632467552512] AH01909: 153.126.200.229:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 25 21:03:53.645213 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 7430:tid 139632467552512] AH01909: 153.126.200.229:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 25 21:33:53.554592 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 7769:tid 140223441197312] AH01909: 153.126.200.229:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 25 21:33:53.571588 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 7769:tid 140223441197312] AH01909: 153.126.200.229:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 25 22:28:49.166069 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 8122:tid 140202116692224] AH01909: 153.126.200.229:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Aug 25 22:28:49.183859 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 8122:tid 140202116692224] AH01909: 153.126.200.229:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

apache log...

```
# cd /etc/httpd/conf
# ls
  httpd-le-ssl.conf
  httpd.conf
  magic
```

```
(httpd.conf)
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.henojiya.net
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

```
(httpd-le-ssl.conf)
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.henojiya.net
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

I hitted the wall... help me! thanks

Comment: This one might help you - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/358089/apache-ssl-server-cert-does-not-include-id-which-matches-server-name

Comment: thanks, i try it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded the view.py again and it was fine.

mysite
|-app1 ...200 ok
|-app2 ...200 ok
|-app3 ...200 ok
|-app4 ...200 ok

I think I was thinking too much.
In the first place, it is stranged that there is only one 500 error.
"View.py" may have been uploaded in a corrupted state.